# Generalized notion of divisor function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progression, divisors-multiples, probabilistic-number-theory

Divisor function $d(n,m)$ counts the number of $q\in\Bbb N$ with $b<q<m$ such that $n\bmod q\equiv0$.

Given $b>0$ what is the correct asymptotic, probabilistic and average case behavior of the function $f(n,m,b)$ that counts the number of $q\in\Bbb N$ with $b<q<m$ such that $n\bmod q\in[-b,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

There is an evident estimate: $f(n)= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=-b}^{i=b} \tau (n+i) + O(b)$ .

P.S. That is for $f(n)=d(n,\sqrt{n})$ in your initial message.

Comment: can you give a tight estimate?

Comment: it is just number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: Yeah I know but how does it behave is the question

Comment: Tau function has no clear asyptotics like most of multiplicative functions. You can find some upper bounds on it and asymtotics of an average here:
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/.